# Use the value of a where variable in other parts of a query

Tags: sql, postgis

Is there anyway that I can use the value of a where option somewhere else in the query? what I'm trying to do is get the points in a map with postgis and return the distance as well in a view so I had this working

```
SELECT name, 
       ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-110 29)')::geography, location:: geography) 
FROM global_points 
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-110 29)'), 1000000);
```

while that's good for a single query, I wanted to use a view to both join some other informations from other tables and so that I can just do

```
SELECT * FROM view WHERE currLoc = POINT(50 50)
```

So that then I would be able to use currLoc in the rest of the view what I'm trying is something like this

```
CREATE VIEW testDis 
AS
SELECT name, ST_Distance(currPos::geography, latlong::geography) 
FROM global_points;
```

it's probably fully wrong but I'm not sure what else I can do.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to "re-use"? The point? The ST_DWithin result? The ST_Distance result?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to reuse the point currPos

Comment: Is `currPos` a column of `global_points`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no it's not, is just a value that I'm hoping I can pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can't have parameters, but you can create a set returning function that can do this:

Something along the lines:

```
create function testDis(currPos geography, latlong geography)
   returns table(text, float)
as $$
  SELECT name, ST_Distance($1, $2) 
  FROM global_points;
$$
language sql;
```

(Sorry I don't know PostGIS so I probably got the data types wrong)

With the above definition you can do something like:

```
select * from testDis(foo, bar);
```

where foo and bar are the approriatly typed values.